# Set intersection with two conditions

Tags: python, csv, set, conditional-statements, intersection

I have the following data set in a CSV file.

```
Entity_A,Category1,Rule1,1990,1992,2
Entity_B,Category1,Rule1,1990,1993,3
Entity_C,Category2,Rule2,1992,1994,2
Entity_A,Category2,Rule2,1992,1993,1
Entity_B,Category2,Rule2,1992,1993,1
Entity_C,Category1,Rule1,1990,1994,4
```

It basically says: Entity_A implemented Rule1 in 1992, where the Rule1 was proposed in 1990. And the time it took to implement is 2 years (subtract 1992-1990).

I have implemented a function that can give how many common rules are there between two states. Here is the code:

```
print set(item[2] for item in L if item[0]=='Entity_A').intersection([item[2] for item in L if item[0]=='Entity_B']) #this gives the common rules between A and B. In this case 2.
```

I want to implement the following:
Lets say if Entity_A implemented a rule in 1992, then the I want to get how many rules does Entity_B implemented AFTER A. In the above data set, the answer would be Entity_A -- Entity_B = 1 because B has implemented 1 rule AFTER A has implemented that rule. **Basically B is following A.**

In this case, I need to compare `item[5]` of A and `item[5]` of B. How can I compare these in the set calculation and compute the results? I basically want to print the following:

Entity_A, Entity_B, 1 --> this is the relation between A and B where B follows A in one rule.

Entity_A, Entity_C, 2 --> C follows a in two rule implementation

Answer (score 1):

```
def numRulesBImplementedAfterA(a, b, L):
    a_date_map = {item[1] : item[3] for item in L if item[0] == a}
    count = 0
    for item in L:
        if item[0] != b:
            continue
        b_rule = item[1]
        b_implemented_date = item[3]
        a_implemented_date = a_date_map.get(b_rule)
        if a_implemented_date is None:
            continue
        if b_implemented_date > a_implemented_date:
            count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: print numRulesBImplementedAfterA('Entity_A', 'Entity_B',  [['Entity_A', 'Rule1', '1990', '1992', '2'], ['Entity_B', 'Rule1', '1990', '1993', '3'], ['Entity_C', 'Rule2', '1992', '1994', '2'], ['Entity_A', 'Rule2', '1992', '1993', '2'], ['Entity_B', 'Rule2', '1992', '1993', '2']]) # for me this gives the correct answer of 1. What happens for you? I think there might be something wrong in the csv reading step.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really compare these with set notation since you're constructing sets without the requisite information. If you want to construct a set with rules Entity_A implemented after Entity_B you're gonna have to do a bit more work:

```
a_impl = [(x[1], x[3]) for x in L if x[0] == 'Entity_A'] # (rule_number, year_implemented)
b_impl = [(x[1], x[3]) for x in L if x[0] == 'Entity_B'] # same for b
b_impl_after_a = filter(lambda k: k[0] == k[2] and k[1] < k[3], [x+y for x in a_impl for y in b_impl])
```

This is off the top of my head so you can probably do this a bit smarter but it works.
a_impl holds two-tuples of all the rules implemented by Entity_A and when they were implemented and likewise for b_impl and Entity_B.

[x+y for x in a_impl for y in b_impl] constructs a cross product for all those rules and the filter just pulls out the ones where the rules are the same and Entity_A implemented before Entity_B.

If you just want the name of the rules you can iterate over the filter:

```
b_impl_after_a = [x[0] for x in b_impl_after_a]
```

Comment: I tried it but it did not give the right answer. I tested it on the same data set mentioned above.

Comment: In [148]: list(b_impl_after_a)                Out[148]: [('Rule1', '1992', 'Rule1', '1993')]              Are you sure? This is what I got from copy pasting my answer...

Comment: k[1]<k[3] is confusing... I am not sure what is wrong with this code... when I am implementing, I am not getting the answer. L = list(result from csv reader).

Comment: This is what my L looks like: In [49]: L
Out[49]:
[['Entity_A', 'Rule1', '1990', '1992', '2'],
 ['Entity_B', 'Rule1', '1990', '1993', '3'],
 ['Entity_C', 'Rule2', '1992', '1994', '2'],
 ['Entity_A', 'Rule2', '1992', '1993', '2'],
 ['Entity_B', 'Rule2', '1992', '1993', '2']]
  So essentially list of lists. If your data is different you might have to change it a bit.

Comment: For the record, k[1] is the year Entity_A implemented rule k[0], k[3] is the year Entity_B implemented the rule k[2].

Answer (score 0):

```
set(item[2] for item in L if (item[0]=='Entity_A' and int(item[5]) == k)).intersection([item[2] for item in L if (item[0]=='Entity_B' and int(item[5]) > k)]) #k is a counter for item[5]
```

Comment: Please add some meaningful explanation along with your code so that the original poster can better understand how your answer solves his problem.